# mysql gaps and islands change time in record before record

Tags: mysql

I have earlier asked a question about how to group from quarters to periods ([MySQL Group from quarters to periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082968/mysql-group-from-quarters-to-periods/62084928))
I have tried to use the last example in the thread - but I have one problem...

Lets say I have some data from a table in the database like this:

```
ma_id   act_tid         act_date    dep client  skillset maske
132 2020-09-11 08:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 08:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 08:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 08:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 12:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  9
132 2020-09-11 12:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  9
132 2020-09-11 12:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 12:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 15:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 15:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 15:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 15:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22
```

I am using the following code to get the groups:

```
ma_id=132
w_t="t.department=1 and t.act_date=20200911 and t.ma_id=" & ma_id
select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(3600000) */
t.ma_id,min(t.act_tid) as start_date,max(t.act_tid) + interval 15 minute as end_date,t.client,t.skillset,t.maske,m.maske as maske_navn,s.skillset as skillset_navn,c.client as client_navn
 from (select t.*,sum(case when prev_act_date >= act_tid - interval 15 minute then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by client, ma_id, skillset, maske, date_format(act_tid,'%d-%m-%Y') order by client asc,ma_id asc,skillset asc,maske asc, act_tid) as grp
 from (select t.*,lag(act_tid) over(partition by client, ma_id, skillset, maske, date_format(act_tid,'%d-%m-%Y') order by client asc,ma_id asc,skillset asc, maske asc, act_tid) as prev_act_date
 from XX.vagter t
 where " & w_t & ") t where " & w_t & ") t
 left join XX.client as c on c.id=t.client
 left join XX.skillset as s on s.id=t.skillset
 left join XX.maske as m on m.id=t.maske
 where " & w_t
 group by t.client, t.ma_id, t.skillset, t.maske, date_format(t.act_tid,'%d-%m-%Y')
, grp order by t.client asc,t.ma_id asc,t.skillset asc, t.maske, min(t.act_tid)
```

My problem is that the output is:

```
132 - 11-09-2020 08:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 - 11-09-2020 16:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 9
```

Which is much better than nothing - but is it possible to get an output like this instead:

```
132 - 11-09-2020 08:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 - 11-09-2020 16:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 9
```

where the line before m (maske) is not null begins 12:00 and not 12:30..?

I have tried without "maske" in group by and order by - and with a left join to find the records where "maske" is not null - but then it is not grouped any longer...

This example above is just a small example from a table with millions of records - and there is many different values for ma_id, client, skillset and maske for each act_date...

Thanks.

[EDIT]:
My desired result should be like the last one above - where the time in 2nd record covers (goes over) the time where maske is not null...
Right now the time is 12:30 for the second record...
So is it possible to always get a record where maske is null before a record where maske is not null - which time-value covers the period in maske...?
Also the end_date should not stop when the record where maske is not null starts - but cover it...

I have tried where I removed maske in the group by statements - and order by statements, and then created a left join to the same table in order to get the rows where maske is not null - but without any luck...
The data cant have same time-period for same ma_id, skillset or client...

[NEW EXAMPLE]
Now the raw data looks like this:

```
132 2020-09-11 08:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  1
132 2020-09-11 08:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  1
132 2020-09-11 08:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  1
132 2020-09-11 08:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  1
132 2020-09-11 09:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 09:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  2
132 2020-09-11 10:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 10:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 11:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 12:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  9
132 2020-09-11 12:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  9
132 2020-09-11 12:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 12:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 13:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 14:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  
132 2020-09-11 15:00:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  10
132 2020-09-11 15:15:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  10
132 2020-09-11 15:30:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22  10
132 2020-09-11 15:45:00 2020-09-11  1   1   22
```

And the result is this:

```
132 - 11-09-2020 08:00:00 - 11-09-2020 09:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 1
132 - 11-09-2020 09:00:00 - 11-09-2020 10:15:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 10:15:00 - 11-09-2020 10:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 2
132 - 11-09-2020 10:30:00 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 9
132 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 - 11-09-2020 15:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 15:00:00 - 11-09-2020 15:45:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 10
132 - 11-09-2020 15:45:00 - 11-09-2020 16:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m:
```

My question is - is it possible to write a sql-string where the result would be:

```
132 - 11-09-2020 08:00:00 - 11-09-2020 09:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m:
132 - 11-09-2020 08:00:00 - 11-09-2020 09:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 1
132 - 11-09-2020 09:00:00 - 11-09-2020 10:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 10:15:00 - 11-09-2020 10:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 2
132 - 11-09-2020 10:30:00 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 12:00:00 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 9
132 - 11-09-2020 12:30:00 - 11-09-2020 15:45:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 
132 - 11-09-2020 15:00:00 - 11-09-2020 15:45:00 c: 1 s: 22 m: 10
132 - 11-09-2020 15:45:00 - 11-09-2020 16:00:00 c: 1 s: 22 m:
```

so there always are a record with null in maske before the record with maske not null - where the row before covers the row with maske not null...?

Another solution for this for me - could also be to use a left join for me to the same table to get the rows where maske is not null - in a given period...
But when I use "min(t.act_tid)" in my left join criterias - an error occurs...
But if the other solution above is possible - it will also be best..

Comment: Your desired result is unclear. You do not actually have rows (e.g. no isle) where maske is null in the period from 12 to 12:30. E.g. ordered by time, it is currently meant to describe 8-12: maske null, 12-12:30: maske 9, 12:30-16: maske null. It's unclear what 12-16: maske null woudl come from, so if you want a different result, you would need to explain where your requirements differ from the original question, so please elaborate on that (and, best, not only the differences). Also: can your data, as in the linked question, have several rows for the same time period?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I still do not understand your requirements. To "get a record where maske is null before a record where maske is not null - which time-value covers the period in maske" I would give you one record 8-16 for maske null (and the one with maske=9). The problem is, that the logic for your result is not evident from your description or sample. Can you modify your example to cover more cases? E.g. rows 8:00-9:00 maske = 1, 10:15-10:30 maske = 2, 12:00-12:15 maske = 9, 15:00-15:45 maske = 10? What would the result be for this?

Comment: Hello Solarflare. Now there is another example above...
Thanks.